# How to generate Issuer thumbprint for WIF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wif

I'm following this [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh987037.aspx) to connect my web application with onpremise ADFS 2.0.

Currently, I'm stuck at the issuer thumbprint section. I have no idea where can I get the thumbprint from.

```
<issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <trustedIssuers>
            <add thumbprint="1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234" name="YourSTSName" />
        </trustedIssuers> 
    </issuerNameRegistry>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the thumprint of the certificate of your STS.  To get that certificate, you needs to contact your sts or read its metadatadocument.
P.e. the AAD STS publishes something like login.microsoftonline.com/38cda3b4-71fa-4748-a48e-e50ef1ebfe00/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml (except for the guid that path is part of the WS-Federation conventions).  There you find the certificates.  If you take the value (from that page) `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`

and save it in a text file with a ".cer" extension, you can view the thumbprint in the properties of the certificate (double-click the file).

However, if you use a newer technology like owin, then you can just read this metadatadocument from your code.  The advantage is that your application always follows whatever certificate changes are needed by the STS.  You don't need any config for that.